# Finding the expected number of success

Tags: self-study, expected-value

The scenario goes like this: a cell phone user has 1/3 of a chance to send a text message, and a 2/3 of a chance to receive a text message.

Question: what is the expected number of text messages received by the cell phone user before they send a text?

Is the answer 1/p = 1/(2/3) = 3/2 = 1.5 messages? (the expected value for a geometric random variable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This indeed concerns geometric distribution but in your guess you make 2 mistakes.

Here "sending a message" must be interpreted as "success" so that $p=\frac13$.

We do not deal with the expected number of **trials** needed to arrive at a success but with the number of **failures** that preceed the first success. In that case the expectation is not $\frac1p$ but equals:$$\frac1p-1=\frac{1-p}p$$
So the correct answer is:$$\frac{1-\frac13}{\frac13}=2$$
A more direct way is solving the equation:$$\mu=\frac23(1+\mu)+\frac13\cdot0$$Here $\mu$ denotes the expectation.

---

Informal confirmation: in a situation like this it will not be surprising to meet sequences like:$$\cdots RRSRRSRRSRRSRRS\cdots$$
($R$ for receive and $S$ for send)

Comment: Please notice that our policy for `[self-study]` questions is to [give hints, not answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @Tim What part of my answer should be left out? Is it sufficient to delete the calculation leading to answer $2$ (starting with: "so the correct answer is...")?

Comment: I'm leaving it up to you, people have different styles of answering such questions. I just wanted to make you aware that we treat such questions slightly differently than others.

Comment: $$\frac{1-p}p$$ as in...[odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds)?

Comment: drhab full post: [Mean of geometric distribution is odds?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590937/mean-of-geometric-distribution-is-odds)

Answer (score 3):

You correctly noticed that the distribution is geometric, i.e. the distribution for "the number of failures before observing a success". The distribution takes two forms (described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)), where the form that would be more useful for you is where $k$ stands for the number of "failures", so the probability mass function is $(1-p)^k p$ and where the expected value is $\tfrac{1-p}{p}$.

The tricky part is finding out what the "success" happening with probability $p$ is and the "failure" happening with probability $1-p$ mean in the problem.

Comment: @drhab see the second paragraph.

Comment: that's interesting...what's the intuition behind why expected value of geometric distribution is $$\frac{1-p}p$$ as in...[odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds)?

Comment: @BCLC no, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Properties , but if you want to ask a question, use questions not comments for it.

Comment: ok thanks. thought it would be a short story.

Comment: Tim, full post: [Mean of geometric distribution is odds?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590937/mean-of-geometric-distribution-is-odds)